# Android, Drawable.createFromStream(is, srcname): what's the 2nd parameter meaning?

Tags: android, drawable

Which is the meaning of the second parameter of Drawable.createFromStream() method?

From Android APIs I only get:

```
public static Drawable createFromStream (InputStream is, String srcName)
Create a drawable from an inputstream
```

In all examples I have read I see they use the string "src": is it the name of the directory where the drawable is cached, relative to my application's root dir?

One parallel question: where am I supposed to find Android core sources (for example of Drawable.createFromStream() method...), to avoid such silly questions, in future?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**It's basically useless**:

Based on [Froyo source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.java#Drawable.drawableFromBitmap%28android.content.res.Resources%2Candroid.graphics.Bitmap%2Cbyte[]%2Candroid.graphics.Rect%2Cjava.lang.String%29), it is used when creating nine-patch images from the resource, but not when creating a regular Bitmap:

```
852 private static Drawable drawableFromBitmap(Resources res, Bitmap bm, byte[] np,
853         Rect pad, String srcName) {
854
855     if (np != null) {
856        return new NinePatchDrawable(res, bm, np, pad, srcName);
857     }
858
859     return new BitmapDrawable(res, bm);
860  }
```

You get there by following the Drawable code:

`createFromStream` returns:

```
return createFromResourceStream(null, null, is, srcName, null);
```

which in turn uses:

```
return drawableFromBitmap(res, bm, np, pad, srcName);
```

(np comes from `Bitmap#getNinePatchChunk();`) and this calls:

```
return new NinePatchDrawable(res, bm, np, pad, srcName);
```

## Finally, you get to the NinePatch declaration:

```
public class NinePatch
```

> Create a drawable projection from a
>   bitmap to nine patches.
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> bitmap The bitmap describing the patches.
>
> chunk The 9-patch data chunk describing how the underlying bitmap
>   is split apart and drawn.
>
> **srcName** The name of the source for the bitmap. **Might be null**.