# Android: Setting Icon in a list View

Tags: android, json, listview, icons, gson

Currently, I have json data of several twitter feeds that I parse to fill my list. I have an object, "image" that contains the url of the users icon that I want to set as the ImageView to in the list. I am having trouble trying to figure out how I can take the url and load the image in the Imageview for each row. Here is the code:

```
public void getTweets(String selection) {
        String formatedcat = selection.toLowerCase();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        JSONObject json = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("http://example.com/tweet.php");

        try {

            JSONArray category = json.getJSONArray(formatedcat);
            for (int i = 0; i < category.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject c = category.getJSONObject(i);

                map.put("id", String.valueOf(i));

                map.put("name",
                        c.getString("fullName") + "\n(#" + c.getString("name")
                                + ") ");
                map.put("text",
                        c.getString("text") + "\n - "
                                + c.getString("timestamp"));
                mylist.add(map);


            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.list,

                new String[] { "name", "text"}, new int[] { R.id.item_title,
                        R.id.item_subtitle});

        setListAdapter(adapter);



        final ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    }
```

Comment: So you say you have the url to the image, right?

Comment: Yes, they would all be similar to this: http://a3.twimg.com//profile_images//1495942710//239346894_normal.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to display image from URL on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407324/how-to-get-image-from-url-in-android)

See this question. Look very practical to me. Do that showing of the image in the `getView()` method where you populate the list and instantiate the child views.

Comment: Hey, The real issue I've been having is how to get the url to my image manager and set it "i" number of different times. I tried map.put("image", c.getString("image")); but can't figure out how to that value to my imagemanager function. Does this make sense?

Comment: When you `Log.i("IMAGE:", c.getString("image"));` do you see the url?

Comment: Good. Now do as I told you, in getView() where you instantiate the imageview do the thing with the image since you have all the urls. do something like `urlList.get(position);` so you have one url per item (thus one picture per item). You got my idea?