# How to set background for an imageView from an image URL?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to load an imageview by url in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)

I am having an image URL.I want to set that image as my ImageViews background.
Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this Link [How to display image from URL on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407324/how-to-get-image-from-url-in-android)

You can then use `setBackgroundDrawable()`  with the drawable created from the URL.

Answer (score 1):

I Hope This code Help you.

```
  public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String url) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    BufferedOutputStream out = null;

    try {
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream(), IO_BUFFER_SIZE);

        final ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(dataStream, IO_BUFFER_SIZE);
        copy(in, out);
        out.flush();

        final byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        //options.inSampleSize = 1;

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,options);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not load Bitmap from: " + url);
    } finally {
        closeStream(in);
        closeStream(out);
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

Then Use `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`