# How to convert string to bitmap in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to load an ImageView by URL in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)

How to convert string to bitmap in android.I am getting url value in string .I want to set bimap in imageview can anybody tell how to do?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android

Answer (score 0):

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407324/how-to-get-image-from-url-in-android) and especially this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6407554/738614) can helps you.

But you also have to care about the picture. Do you want to reuse it later? It that case, you can save it in your cache.

Comment: What do you mean with "cache"? The SD card, the RAM?

Comment: You can implement your own cache. Using [SoftReference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html) or implementing your own cache (on sdcard, for example).
[Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) is a good article to read about Android.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Prime](https://github.com/DHuckaby/Prime), I use it for all of my image loading.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android) has the basic approach. Essentially, you need to first download the image from the URL, then you can set it to an `ImageView`, save it to your phone's SD card, etc.

If you're comfortable looking through other people's source code, [this GitHub project](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) shows you how you can store the image locally for reuse, run image downloads in a background thread, download multiple images for `ListView`s, etc.