# showing image use after input text URL and press button

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-edittext, imagebutton

i have error code help me to fix it, getting text URL from edittext after click button and showing image on imageView,

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button bt;
EditText et;
ImageView iv;
Runnable stream;

    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    loadGambar();

    stream = new Runnable() {



@Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                loadGambar();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getStackTrace();
            }
            new Handler().postDelayed(stream, 2);
        }
    };
    new Handler().postDelayed(stream, 2);
}

private void loadGambar(){
    try {
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);



bt.setOnClickListener(new view.OnClickListener() {  
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    et   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                    iv.setBackground(et.getText().toString());

            }
        });



URL url = new URL (et.getText().toString());
        InputStream is =  (InputStream) url.getContent();
        Drawable gambar = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
        iv.setImageDrawable(gambar);
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

acitvity_main.xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:ems="10" android:inputType="textUri">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:text="@string/button" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
```

how i can show after input URL to edittext and pressed button to show image from URL

Comment: What error you getting ? And can u tell briefly what you trying to achieve.

Comment: i am error on the bt.setClickOnlistener,

Comment: What error you getting. Paste your Logcat trace

Answer (score 0):

You trying to set String as a background of your **Imageview**. You need to load Image from URL. Read this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/) for fetching Image from URL Or check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407324/how-to-get-image-from-url-in-android).

Comment: i getting error on              iv.setBackground(et.getText().toString()); how i fix it ? i have to moving SetClickListener

Comment: how to change it in order to display the image? i am newbie on android

Comment: ok i try that's toturial and if i have error i send to you error code and image to

Comment: still can be solved, i have two activity but after click button and move to other activity but URL can be get text from edittext after click button

Comment: gmail name of you rahul ? i will send it now

Comment: rahul1604kapoor@gmail.com

Comment: ok i am sending you is done, last 15second ago, you can check email

Answer (score 0):

1. First you have to download Android query jar from [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/detail?name=android-query-full.0.25.10.jar).

   Android query is easily downloaded or load image from URL based on AJAX call.
2. Add jar to project libs folder and add jar to build path.
3. Activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button bt;
EditText et;
ImageView iv;

private AQuery androidQuery;

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);
et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
androidQuery = new AQuery(this);

bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if(et.getText().toString().trim().length()>0){
        // this code load image form url
         androidQuery.image(et.getText().toString(), true, true); 
                                /*or*/
         // this code download image
         androidQuery.ajax(et.getText().toString(), Bitmap.class, 0, new AjaxCallback<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void callback(String url, Bitmap object, AjaxStatus status) {
                    super.callback(url, object, status);
                    if(object!=null){
                        iv.setImageBitmap(object);
                    }else{
                        // write message if give path image not found
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
}



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
      return true;
    }
```