# how to detect the images from url is portrait or landscape(Android)

Tags: java, android

Any idea or suggestion that can be done to detect the images from url is portrait or landscape. I need to display different size if portrait `scaletype:fix_center` and is landscape `scaletype:fixXY.`

Answer (score 0):

As long as landscape means wider than taller (and portrait viceversa) it means to read the image into memory and check width and height.

To read image look here: [How to display image from URL on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407324/how-to-get-image-from-url-in-android) .

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) to read EXIF information from the pic (sounds more correct, but PeterMmm's solution may be easier to implement)