# Displaying an image from url on Fragment

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments, imageview

I have looked all around the internet but cant find an answer because i keep on getting errors from them. Im trying to make a picture from a url to show up on the image view, any help please? thank you very much :D

Here is my code for my fragment

```
package com.TripleC.twenty20;

import com.TripleC.twenty20.R;
import com.TripleC.twenty20.R.layout;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class PagesFragment extends Fragment {

public PagesFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pages, container, false);
       return rootView;


}   
}
```

I try this

```
try {
  ImageView i = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageUrl).getContent());
  i.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But it tells me i cant use the findviewbyid "The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type PagesFragment"

This is the new error that comes up when i click the fragment, Logcat:

```
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:190)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at java.net.URL.getContent(URL.java:447)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at com.TripleC.twenty20.PhotosFragment.onCreateView(PhotosFragment.java:30)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
12-27 03:13:32.138: E/AndroidRuntime(1989):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please provide more code, how you are fetching the image from url and setting it on image view

Comment: Thats the problem, I do not know how

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407324/how-to-get-image-from-url-in-android

Comment: I think ur triying to findout this
 [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2472175/793943

Comment: use SmartImageView instead of ImageView, you can find it by Googling it.

Comment: Is this what you have tried ?

Comment: Only errors pop up and say to remove invalid modifiers

Comment: But you have to declare variable some misPlace or any syntax error so problem created

Comment: "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException". Your error looks like it requires AsyncTask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you access the views in your fragment then you need access it as `view.findViewById` as i have done below:

Try out as below:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pages, container, false);

    try {
      ImageView i = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);
      Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageUrl).getContent());
      i.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
       return rootView;


}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the app crashes when i click on that fragment

Comment: @Crazycriss what it says??

Comment: Are you trying to perform some time consuming tasks in the main thread of the application in your `PhotosFragment.onCreateView(` method?

Comment: Please don`t download content on the main Thread. Use a Handler with a Thread or AsyncTaks with a Callback Interface, or a third party library and so on. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
  ImageView i = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageUrl).getContent());
  i.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

write your code in block of onActivityCreated

```
  @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
           //write your code here
        }
```