# Get pictures-url and text-url in Android

Tags: java, android

I've developed an Android-application, which parses a web-page and as a result return pictures and texts from it. But when I show my application code to my customer, he said, he want me to write my application  using more easy algorithm: application must find picture-urls and text-urls, and then show a content using founded urls. How to do it?

This a parsing class from my application:

```
public class NetworkConnect extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> 
      {
        //Background processing
            ProgressDialog parsingBar = ProgressDialog.show(StackParser.this, "Working...", "requesting to URL and parsing content", true, false);
            protected Void doInBackground(String... arg) 
            {   
              try 
              {   
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, arg[0]);
                Document doc;
                Elements urls;
                Elements data;
                Intent intent = new Intent(StackParser.this, AvailableContent.class);
                doc = Jsoup.connect(arg[0]).timeout(10000).get();
                data = doc.getAllElements();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Data: " + data.toString());
                stringData = doc.text();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "String data: " + stringData.toString());
                urls = doc.select("[href$=.png]");
                imageURL = urls.get(0).attr("href");
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "imageURL = " + imageURL);
                if(!stringData.equals(""))
                {
                    intent.putExtra("Send to the content-activity", stringData);
                    intent.putExtra("Send imagesURLs to the content-activity", imageURL);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
                else
                {
                    intent.putExtra("Send to the content-activity", "empty");
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
              }
              catch (IOException e) 
              {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
              } //catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                //e.printStackTrace();
            //}
            return null;
            }
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
            {
              //Убираем диалог загрузки
                parsingBar.dismiss();
            }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Are you getting Urls from this Async task ??

Comment: @BalvinderSingh, No, this Async task parses web-page.

Comment: Log.d(LOG_TAG, "imageURL = " + imageURL); what this line printing??

Comment: @BalvinderSingh, It prints url, which connected with a picture on web-page.

Comment: If you want to get bitmap from Url then use my answer

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with

```
public static Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
try {
    InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
    return d;
} catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
}
```

[How to display image from URL on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407324/how-to-get-image-from-url-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
      image.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(url, 200, 200));

     public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        Bitmap bm = null;
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        //  Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options); 

        return bm;   
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(

        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            if (width > height) {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);    
            } else {
                inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);    
            }   
        }

        return inSampleSize;    
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int arg0, long arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
```