# How to create image from webService, Android

Tags: java, android, json, imageurl

So, I have this app that is connected to a WebService and I am already retrieving data from there, now I want to retrieve a image link and make that the imageView gets that image trough the link. Is that even possible? Appreciate any help :D

```
        @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
        Log.e(TAG, "Response from URL: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {

                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    JSONArray paises = jsonObject.optJSONArray("paises");

                    if (paises != null) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < paises.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = paises.getJSONObject(j);
                            System.out.println(jsonObject1.optString("Designacao"));
                            String K_PAIS = jsonObject1.getString("K_PAIS");
                            String Designacao = jsonObject1.getString("Designacao");
                            String URL_IMAGE_SMALL = jsonObject1.getString("URL_IMAGE_SMALL");
                            String URL_IMAGEM = "http://something.something.pt" + URL_IMAGE_SMALL;

                            new DownloadImage(imageView6).execute(URL_IMAGEM);

                            HashMap<String, String> pais = new HashMap<>();

                            pais.put("K_PAIS", K_PAIS);
                            pais.put("Designacao", Designacao);
                            pais.put("URL_IMAGE_SMALL", URL_IMAGE_SMALL);
                            pais.put("URL_IMAGEM", URL_IMAGEM);
                            listaPaises.add(pais);


                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(jsonObject.optString("Designacao"));
                }



            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json parsin error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errpr!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
        return null;



    }
{...}
public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImage(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = (ImageView) bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Error", e.getStackTrace().toString());

        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display image from URL on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407324/how-to-display-image-from-url-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), a wonderful image library.

Example:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

Add dependency via Gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use any third party library 
example use `Glide` library

this library will help you to fetch and display image on `ImageView` from `url`.

example:

```
Glide.with(context).load(image_url).into(your_image_view);
```

here is link for that library : https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your ImageView inside your XML as you normally do. Then you can use any third party library like [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) that will load the image from the url and set it to your ImageView in your activity/fragment.

Answer (score 0):

In your app build.gradle add

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

use this code to load image from url

```
 Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load("image_url").into(ImageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this if you dont want to use third party library**

```
 new DownloadImage(imamgeview).execute(url);
```

**create a Async Task**

```
 public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    CircleImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImage(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = (CircleImageView) bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Error", e.getStackTrace().toString());

        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

**i hope you it will work in your case**

Comment: So just to clarify, in  "new DownloadImage(imamgeview).execute(url);" the "url" is the variable where the link is saved, right?

Comment: no the app crashes... I have this variable (URL_IMAGEM) which is a String from the json and I add it to the execute(), but no luck

Comment: can u please paste your code here so i can help you

Comment: commnt your url here

Comment: Didn't understood what URL?

Answer (score 0):

**step 1:** create class named DownloadImage

```
public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    CircleImageView bmImage;

    public DownloadImage(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = (CircleImageView) bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Error", e.getStackTrace().toString());

        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** execute AsyncTask

```
new DownloadImage(imgUserProfile).execute(userProfileUrl);
```

**Json Url like this: **   https://graph.facebook.com/1220130444748799/picture?height=400&width=400&migration_overrides=%7Boctober_2012%3Atrue%7D