# Android: json response, google api and getting image from url

Tags: android, json, google-api, drawable, android-bitmap

I'm using google books api to get some data as json response.
in the response, there are JSONArrays, each element is a book and it contains data about it. the problem is the elements should be symmetric when it comes to the data they contain. in other words, each element should contain a title, authors, book cover url, rating and so on. and when a book doesn't contain ,for example, a rating, this value should exist and be empty but it doesn't exist at all for that element so in the for loop it throws an exception

[image: the exception message]

so what should i do to avoid such a problem and i do need that data even if it's empty.

---

the other part is there is a url for the cover of the book provided in the response. i want to get that image. i tried both top answers [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407324/how-to-display-image-from-url-on-android) and non of them seemed to work.

Comment: Sounds like pretty basic stuff. `if (! json.obj) { // show default or something } else { // do your code }`

Comment: Show your code, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use optJSONObject instead of getJSONObject to get JSONObject.
*Note: getJSONObject will through error if the object don't have the key, but optJSONObject will just return null if the object don't have value*

```
JSONArray array = null;// your array
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = array.optJSONObject(i);

                if(jsonObject == null) {
                    continue;
                }

    //            JSONObject ratingObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("rating"); // Dont use this
                JSONObject ratingObject = jsonObject.optJSONObject("rating");

                if(ratingObject != null) {
                    // Do someting here
                }
            }
```

For Image loading you can use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) lib it may help you.