# Android ImageSize Increases after downloading | Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

I have an image stored on my server whose size is 89kb.

```
https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/images.crownit.in/emailer/push_banner_tambola_01072017_v2.jpg
```

However, after I download the bitmap using Picasso, The byteCount comes out to be 2 MB.

```
double lengthbmp = bitmap.getByteCount(); //1920000 Bytes
```

Is this anything to do with the resolution of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the size change is due to a change in file format. The file is hosted as a JPEG, however you are converting it to a bitmap in your application. I converted the file using photoshop to give an example of the difference in file size based on format:

[image]

In terms of network load you will still only move the 89kb, as the file only increases in size when converted to bitmap in your application.

If you really want to maintain the JPG format follow the answer given in the following post: [How to display image from URL on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407324/how-to-display-image-from-url-on-android)