# HOW TO Retrieve Image from URL using Firebase Realtime Database / ask code?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

HOW TO Retrieve Image from URL using Firebase Realtime Database

ask code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUJpR.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a library like `Glide` from Google: https://github.com/bumptech/glide or `Picasso`: http://square.github.io/picasso/

`Glide` example: `GlideApp.with(this).load("http://your_URL").into(imageView);`

Comment: Test will tell.

Comment: Hi Angelina / Url from Firebase Realtime Database

Comment: hi @EkdanaiNantaharn, i suppose your url points to Firebase Storage or other server where the image is stored and the library downloads it.

Comment: Hi @Angelina, Firebase Storage

Comment: Hi @Angelina, See image above

Comment: @EkdanaiNantaharn does this URL work? then use the `Glide` to get the image and put it into `ImageView` or you can use alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407324/how-to-display-image-from-url-on-android

Comment: url to Firebase realtime database  See image above