# Why is this image bitmap not downloading in Android?

Tags: android

I have an appliation in which I have to download an image from an URL. I am using the following code for the same:

```
URL url = new URL(address);
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.connect();
int length = conn.getContentLength();
is = conn.getInputStream();
bis = new BufferedInputStream(is, length);
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
```

The bm which is returned for some reason has height and width -1, and this is throwning Illegal state exception. What could be the reason that height and width is coming -1?

Answer (score 1):

You should check what the length field returns. Most of these types of methods return -1 as the content length if the download failed

Comment: conn.length() is returning 16333 bytes

Answer (score 1):

Please look below code

```
String url = server url;
InputStream ins = null;
    try {
        ins = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(ins));
imageview.setImageBitmap(b);
```

And used below function also

```
 static class FlushedInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
    public FlushedInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
        super(inputStream);
    }

    @Override
    public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
        long totalBytesSkipped = 0L;
        while (totalBytesSkipped < n) {
            long bytesSkipped = in.skip(n - totalBytesSkipped);
            if (bytesSkipped == 0L) {
                int b = read();
                if (b < 0) {
                    break; // we reached EOF
                } else {
                    bytesSkipped = 1; // we read one byte
                }
            }
            totalBytesSkipped += bytesSkipped;
        }
        return totalBytesSkipped;
    }
}
```

Comment: what does src name refer to here. i can put anything? the documentation is not clear on this...

Comment: Please check link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122599/android-drawable-createfromstreamis-srcname-whats-the-2nd-parameter-meaning

Comment: thanks for your response but the code that you have given is not working. sometimes the drawable comes null from the source and sometimes even if it does when i set it by setImageDrawable().. an exception is being thrown.

Comment: please check answer i have update it i think it is more helpful to you.

Comment: any query then let me know. if you find this is helpful then right answer and upvote it so more help to other also.

Comment: nopes the server that i was downloading from has creashed for some reason. hence have not been able to try it. thanks though. i will get back to you as soon as i done downloading.