# Android Testing - create shortcut on home screen

Tags: android, homescreen, android-testing

Is it possible to create a shortcut on home screen for the tested application?
I have an application which I test. During the tests the app is uninstalled and reinstalled. The uninstallation removes the home screen shortcut.

Is there a way to recreate it within a testing activity?
I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337431/android-create-shortcuts-on-the-home-screen), but it does not answer my question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754953/homescreen-shortcuts-with-icons

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't implemented in a testing activity.

Answer (score 0):

just use the same key and name and don't uninstall it. It sees it as an update and keeps the icon