# Load images in Html.fromHtml in textview (JSON String)

Tags: android, json, image-load

I am Having Problem with Loading Images from a website to a TextView using JSON string parsing. I was trying to load images with the help of Html.ImageGetter and BitmapDrawable. I saw these references [Load images in Html.fromHtml in textview (http url images, Base64 url images)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22936653/load-images-in-html-fromhtml-in-textview-http-url-images-base64-url-images/35442703#35442703) and [Android HTML ImageGetter as AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424512/android-html-imagegetter-as-asynctask)

I am not understanding why am I having Null Pointer Exception.
I am trying to load "content" string from http://techmasi.com/wp-json/posts this JSON link.

Here's my codes

```
public class URLDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
// the drawable that you need to set, you could set the initial drawing
// with the loading image if you need to
protected Drawable drawable;

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    // override the draw to facilitate refresh function later
    if(drawable != null) {
        drawable.draw(canvas);
    }
}}
```

Here's Another Class:

```
public class URLImageParser implements Html.ImageGetter {
Context context;
TextView container;

public URLImageParser(TextView t, Context c) {
    this.context = c;
    this.container = t;
}

public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
    URLDrawable urlDrawable = new URLDrawable();

    // get the actual source
    ImageGetterAsyncTask asyncTask =
            new ImageGetterAsyncTask( urlDrawable);

    asyncTask.execute(source);

    // return reference to URLDrawable where I will change with actual image from
    // the src tag
    return urlDrawable;
}

public class ImageGetterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable> {
    URLDrawable urlDrawable;

    public ImageGetterAsyncTask(URLDrawable d) {
        this.urlDrawable = d;
    }

    @Override
    protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
        String source = params[0];
        return fetchDrawable(source);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
        // set the correct bound according to the result from HTTP call
        Log.d("height", "" + result.getIntrinsicHeight());
        Log.d("width",""+result.getIntrinsicWidth());
        urlDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0+result.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0+result.getIntrinsicHeight());
        // change the reference of the current drawable to the result
        // from the HTTP call
        urlDrawable.drawable = result;
        // redraw the image by invalidating the container
        URLImageParser.this.container.invalidate();
        // For ICS
        URLImageParser.this.container.setHeight((URLImageParser.this.container.getHeight()
                + result.getIntrinsicHeight()));
        // Pre ICS
        URLImageParser.this.container.setEllipsize(null);
    }
}


public Drawable fetchDrawable(String urlString) {
    try {
        InputStream is = fetch(urlString);
        Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0
                + drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        return drawable;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

private InputStream fetch(String urlString) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlString);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    return response.getEntity().getContent();
}}
```

I am getting NullPointer Exception in the following line:

```
urlDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0+result.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0+result.getIntrinsicHeight());
```

Logcat Output:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.droiddigger.techmasi.URLImageParser$ImageGetterAsyncTask.onPostExecute(URLImageParser.java:64)
        at com.droiddigger.techmasi.URLImageParser$ImageGetterAsyncTask.onPostExecute(URLImageParser.java:48)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please Help.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not using Drawable.createFromStream(). It's essentially not documented and [doesn't do what you need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122599/android-drawable-createfromstreamis-srcname-whats-the-2nd-parameter-meanin).  I bet it's returning null.

If you need to decode a Bitmap from an InputStream that contains a PNG, JPG, GIF, or other Android-supported image type, try [BitmapFactory.decodeStream()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream(java.io.InputStream)), and then create a Drawable from that bitmap.

Comment: Have you tried running this through a step through debug session?  Saying "not working" is not really helping us know what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry for that but I don't understand step through debug session as I am beginner in android. I just made the following changes in fetchDrawable Method 
         `InputStream is = fetch(urlString);
            Bitmap btmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            Drawable drawable=new BitmapDrawable(Resources.getSystem(),btmp);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0
                    + drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
            return drawable;`

Comment: Google "Debugging in Android".